# Puppy pees when touched or scolded

Tags: dogs, behavior

One of my female dog gave puppies 4 months ago. One of the girl pup, that's not adopted by anyone yet, still is with us.
The thing is, she's brave and confident, but pees when scolded, or when we try to scare or shoo her. After that, she keeps wagging her tail and comes to us for us to pet her, but pees again on the first touch.
I've had dogs my whole life, but haven't seen this kind of behavior before. Why is she so scared? How can we teach her not to be?

Also to mention, my young cousins live in the same house, they might tease or hurt her slightly in our absence, but that's happened with all our dogs before too. None of them behaved like she does.

Answer (score 7):

The first dog I had (decades ago) used to pee every time I came home after being a work. It wasn't because she was scared. She was just excited to see me and couldn't hold it -- even though she didn't have any "accidents" in the house while I was gone. Try calling your puppy to the door and greeting her outside. Then you can praise her for toileting outside instead of in. Even though it wasn't her intention to do that.

If that doesn't seem possible, then just ignore her when you come in the door. Set all of your things down, get a glass of water (or other beverage) and *then* say 'hello' to her. You will be letting her calm herself down which may help tremendously to ease the excitement.

Also, please work with your younger cousins and help them understand that it isn't nice to tease and hurt other living creatures.

Answer (score 5):

Her reaction may not be from fear. Rather, it may be *[submissive urination](https://www.google.com/search?q=submissive%20urination)*.

From https://www.humanesociety.org/resources/dog-submissive-urination-solutions:

> In a pack, dogs have many ways to show the leader that they accept
>   their role as top dog and thus avoid a confrontation. One way is to
>   roll on their backs and urinate on themselves.
>
> Submissive urination is common and normal in puppies, who will usually
>   outgrow the behavior. But some puppies remain timid into adulthood,
>   and submissive urination can become a problem in the home.